# Need help identifying why route segment not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I'm writing a .net core 3.1 web api and having issues with a basic route segment.  I'm getting 404 not-found conditions when I attempt to pass my "id" as a segment.

e.g.  servername/api/contacts/getsmscontactlist/3

Here's my startup.cs:

```
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "MainAPIRouteForGet",
                pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    });
```

And here's my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowAllHeaders")]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IContactManager _contactManager;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public ContactsController(IContactManager contactManager, IConfiguration config)
{
    _contactManager = contactManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contactManager));
    _configuration = config;
}

[HttpGet("{id}:int")]
[Route("getsmscontactlist")]
public ActionResult GetSmsContactsForAccount(int id)
{
    var smsRecipientsViewModel = _contactManager.GetSmsContactsForAccount(id);

    if (smsRecipientsViewModel.Any())
    {
        return Ok(smsRecipientsViewModel);
    }

    return NotFound("No SMS contacts found");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where it goes wrong:

```
//NOTE: this is incorrect, the correct pattern should be {id:int}
[HttpGet("{id}:int")]
[Route("getsmscontactlist")]
public ActionResult GetSmsContactsForAccount(int id)
```

You use 2 attributes (each of which can specify a route pattern) for the method. That will create 2 routes `{id:int}` and `getsmscontactlist`. The second route does not help bind the `id` via route value at all whereas the first route can bind the `id` value but lacks the meaningful segment. With those routes, the testing url would be like `servername/api/contacts/3` (matched the first route) or `servername/api/contacts/getsmscontactlist?id=3` (matched the second route).

However looks like you want to use just one route, so it should be something like this:

```
[HttpGet("getsmscontactlist/{id:int}")]
public ActionResult GetSmsContactsForAccount(int id)
```

Now you can use your original testing URL: `servername/api/contacts/getsmscontactlist/3`

Comment: Thank you very, VERY much.  I actually saw it working with "...?id=3" and was confused by that but didn't want to cloud the question.  I sincerely appreciate your answer.   Yours in tech, JK.

Comment: @JoeKehnast you're welcome, feel free to accept the answer otherwise it does not look helpful (not standing out).

Comment: NP King King. I don't ask many questions on this forum so forgot to do that.  Thanks again my friend.  Yours in code, JK.

Comment: @JoeKehnast OK, please note that, asking too many questions without accepting or upvotes may be considered as not-contributing. That's when you may not be able to ask more, until you give your answers to contribute more .... That's how SO works. But now you know it. Keep asking & answering if you can, thanks!